# Push spark current_timestamp value to postgres timestamp with timezone column

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I need to push 'start_time' value to postgres table which has column with 'timestamp with timezone' datatype. I need solution only in java jdbc connection only please.

```
import spark.implicits._ 
val df1 =Seq(("Process Name","Process Description"))
                         .toDF("process_nm","process_desc") 
val df2 = df1.withColumn("start_time",current_timestamp)  
df2.show(false)             
df2.printSchema

df2.collect().foreach(row=>
 {    
     println("Before calling-"+row.getString(0)+"   "+row.getString(1)+"   
                                         "+row.getTimestamp(2))
    
     var process_name:String=row.getString(0)
     var process_description:String=row.getString(1) 
     var start_time=row.getTimestamp(2)
     var insertSql="""insert into test_log(process_nm,start_time,process_desc) 
                       values('$process_name','$start_time','$process_description')""" 

     import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
     import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
     import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{concat, lit}

     import java.io.File
     import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager}
 
     var db_conn_string = "jdbc:" + db_type + "://" + db_host + ":" + db_port + "/" + db_database
     val direct_conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_conn_string, db_user, db_pass)
     val statement = direct_conn.createStatement()
     val result=statement.executeUpdate(insertSql)
     println("inserted-"+result)

     println("insert_sql-"+insertSql)  
})
```

Getting below error while pushing start_time to postgres table

```
Before calling-Process Name   Process Description   2021-12-06 05:51:12.278559
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "$start_time"
  Position: 93
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2552)
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:322)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:258)
  at $anonfun$res19$1(<pastie>:57)
  at $anonfun$res19$1$adapted(<pastie>:32)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 var insertSql="insert into test_log(process_nm,start_time,process_desc) 
                       values('$process_name','$start_time','$process_description')"
```

You don't want to use """ as it doesn't allow variable substitution.

As an aside, where possible I would also suggest using 'val' instead of 'var' for performance.

Comment: I believe its not complaining about quotes. Spark is unable to convert 'start_time' into postgres's timestamp with timezone datatype. Is there any way I can convert it into timestamp with timezone format?

Comment: It's not complaining about the quotes I agree and you are correct in that postgress cannot interpret what you are sending but the issue is that you are literally sending "$start_time".  Your error message states this above.  FYI look into """  it is the raw interpolator for scala and does not do variable interpolation.

Comment: If you feel this answer was helpful and you are comfortable could you mark it as correct?

Comment: I tried with single double quotes and still same issue.

Comment: Can you update the question with your updated code?